# "Multiple company" design pattern

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design

Is there such thing as a "Multi Company" design pattern for databases? We were being told the other day by a professor that this is a relatively simple feature to add in design time and that we should apply it to any software that may be used by more than one company at the time or for example by a corporation (D) that is made out of company A,B,C.

What he suggested was in general terms was this.

- All catalogs should include the ID of the company.
- All reports should include in their input parameters, the company for
  which the report is run or whether it is for all companies

For example...

[image]

Is this an accepted way to model databases that will hold multiple companies'registers without mixing them?

Is there a better more efficient way?

I ask because it wouldn't be the first time we're told something that is quite outdated and I would appreciate any insight into current design trends (or where to find them)

Cheers.

Comment: If `Sells_Log` belongs to `Sells_Catalog`, there is no need to have `idCatalog` on it - you can join through `Sells_Catalog`.

Comment: You may be interested in reading about [Multitenancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy).

Comment: @Amadan you're right of course, but say we didn't have idCompany on the Sells_Log, would that be more efficient? Suppose that the idCompany makes it easier to bypass queries where the  Catalog is not needed and you're only interested in the Log for each company.

Comment: @jaco0646 Excellent! Thanks I didn't knew the exact term for this. Kinda sounds like SaaS in some aspects.

Comment: My proposal is a tiny bit less time-efficient (as long as you have proper indices), somewhat more space-efficient, and much more resistant to catalogs changing companies (if that is a possibility in your data model).

Comment: @Amadan, it is. Right now I'm bouncing ideas and comparing them to the example I was originally given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different considerations here:

**Technical Considerations**

From a purely technical point of view there's no reason that a Multi Company database should be modelled any differently than a Multi Anything database. By that, any categorisation will lead to that particular Category Id being propagated throughout the database as a Foreign Key to maintain category separation.

So from a Database technology perspective this is very simple and very possible.

**Architectural Considerations**

The type of application your database is supporting will also weigh into an appropriate design. For instance, if you were planning to host a Software As A Service application which was transaction heavy you may wish to run multiple instances for multiple companies to cater for thing such as performance, utilisation, licensing etc. This is one of a million examples of an architectural consideration outside the limitation of the Database technology.

So from an Architectural perspective you have many options including all companies in a single instance, multiple instances per company, or a mixture of the two (transaction heavy tables on a per-company basis and shared tables in a shared zone / database).

**Legal / License Considerations**

There may be issues for housing cross company data within the same database, or potentially even on the same machine (virtual or otherwise). This could also be a reason that requires you to rethink your architecture, which will in turn require a rethink in Database design.

**Summary**

As you can see there are many (and many more than I listed) reasons that could lead to an architectural change that then leads your database design in one way or another. But speaking purely technically, in a generic sense, there's nothing wrong with having a "Company ID" propagated throughout relevant tables and have your application or database level security operate to ensure that each company only gets their own data surfaced to them.

In real cases you'll have a lot more considerations that would influence your decision (I know many companies I've worked for have required separation of particular sets of data by law or regulation for instance).

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation, I'll try to read more on this whole multi tenant thing to gain a deeper understanding on which options are avaible and when to apply them. If you have any literature sugestions please let me know!